# Angular 2 test swallowing promise

Tags: javascript, angular

Testing an angular 2 component but it seems to be swallowing a promise. I've set up an inner expect that should always fail (expect false to be true) but it doesn't throw an exception and causes the test to pass. Any thoughts?

Using ng2 rc1

test

```
import { it, ddescribe, expect, inject, async, beforeEachProviders } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { provide } from '@angular/core';
import {
  TestComponentBuilder,
  ComponentFixture
} from '@angular/compiler/testing';
import { Http, BaseRequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { LoginComponent } from './..';
import { MockBackend } from '@angular/http/testing';
import { UserService } from '../../';

ddescribe('LoginThing', () => {
  it('should wrap content', async(inject([TestComponentBuilder], (tcb: TestComponentBuilder) => {
    console.log('Ready to run test');
    return tcb.createAsync(LoginComponent)
        .then((fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent>) => {
          console.log(fixture);
          fixture.detectChanges();
          var compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
          expect(compiled).toContainText('stuff');
          expect(false).toBe(true);
        });
  })));
});
```

karma testing shim

```
/*global jasmine, __karma__, window*/
Error.stackTraceLimit = Infinity;
jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 1000;

__karma__.loaded = function () {
};

var distPath = '/base/.test/';
var appPath = distPath + 'app/';

function isJsFile(path) {
  return path.slice(-3) == '.js';
}

function isSpecFile(path) {
  return path.slice(-8) == '.spec.js';
}

function isAppFile(path) {
  return isJsFile(path) && (path.substr(0, appPath.length) == appPath);
}

var allSpecFiles = Object.keys(window.__karma__.files)
  .filter(isSpecFile)
  .filter(isAppFile);

// Load our SystemJS configuration.
System.config({
  baseURL: distPath,
});


System.import('system.config.js').then(function(e) {
  // Load and configure the TestComponentBuilder.
  return Promise.all([
    System.import('@angular/core/testing'),
    System.import('@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing')
  ]).then(function (providers) {
    var testing = providers[0];
    var testingBrowser = providers[1];
    testing.setBaseTestProviders(
      testingBrowser.TEST_BROWSER_DYNAMIC_PLATFORM_PROVIDERS,
      testingBrowser.TEST_BROWSER_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_PROVIDERS
    );
  });
}).then(function() {
  return Promise.all(
    allSpecFiles.map(function (moduleName) {
      return System.import(moduleName);
    }));
}).then(__karma__.start, __karma__.error);
```